# How to encode WebP animation on Android

Tags: android, animation, webp

I can't find any documentation or example code on how to create an animation file in the WebP format on Android. I know how to encode one WebP image from a Bitmap. I also know there exists a webpmux command line utility to combine multiple WebP images into one WebP file containing multiple frames. What I don't know is how to do this from Java code.

I'm perfectly happy with using a high version Android SDK, 4.3+ is fine, which means WebP should be fully supported.

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: Nope, but it's been almost 6 years since, maybe there is now

Comment: Any updates? @UsamaSaeedUS

Comment: i ended up using ffmpeg, which i wanted to avoid, and ffmpeg increase the app size 10mb at least in case we use a bundle for store.

Comment: ffmpeg has animated webp encoder? I read that ffmpege does not support that